# HTML input type=file multiple - When publish app to IIS, only one file can be selected at a time

Tags: html, asp.net, iis, multipartform-data

I have a basic form using `<input type="file" multiple>` to upload multiple files.  It works fine when I'm developing (IIS Express) but when I publish the site to IIS, the multi-select only allows one file to be selected at a time.  This behavior is consistent across all browsers and the page source at the browser is identical.

Is there a setting on IIS that could be causing this?

Here is the form code:

```
<form action="/Home/SubmitFiles" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select one or more documents to convert:</label>
        <input name="files" id="files" type="file" multiple>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Convert</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How is your rendered html?

Comment: Selecting one vs. multiple files is an operation in a browser and cannot depend on the server, if the HTML is identical. There must be something here that was not described in the question. Maybe you mean that the server does not process all submitted files?

Comment: The example is the html at the browser.  

I know you can limit the number of files from a server-side setting.  It acts as if that setting is set to one.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. *multiple* is a html5 feature for *input*. After testing in IE10 with "IE7-Emulate" turned on, I've found an interesting thing: I turned proxy server off and multiple selecting suddenly start working with all browsers. First think was: "my proxy rewrites headers". I tried to modify popup page by adding . Multiselection started to work in IE10. There is no support for multiselection in IE7,8,9. If you want to use this versions of IE, you should try Flash or custom ActiveX controls.